# What statistical test is appropriate for the following experimental design, apart from mixed two-way ANOVA?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, experiment-design

We are planning a study of the effectiveness of two therapies for treating depression. Group A will receive the current therapy and group B will receive a new and improved therapy. Participants are randomly assigned to one of the therapy groups. A measure of depression is taken twice: before and after therapy. We are trying to decide if the new therapy is more effective than the current approach.

I know we could use mixed two-way factorial (2 by 2) ANOVA. Could you offer any other approaches that would make sense?

Would multiple regression also make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also treat the before-measure as a covariate in either a regression model with a treatment dummy indicator or in an ANOVA with before as covariate and a single factor (treatment). These two methods will produce an identical result for the test of the treatment effect (i.e., different output but the same underlying model).